# Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup unix on 172.25.160.1:53: no such host

Tags: docker, kubernetes, wsl-2, k3d

Guys I need some help =)

I am trying to install docker/kubernetes/k3d/devspace on a wsl2 ubuntu machine...
My docker seems to be running fine

After creating a k3d cluster like this:

```
k3d cluster create dev --port 8080:80@loadbalancer --port 8443:443@loadbalancer
```

I am getting an error message when running `kubectl cluster-info`:

> Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup unix on 172.25.160.1:53: no such host

Do you guys have any tips where I could start looking for the problem? I am lost

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, apparently the kubeconfig server url set to https://unix:6443 cannot be accessed.

Try starting the cluster with --api-port 127.0.0.1:6443

This will set the server property to 127.0.0.1:6443 instead of unix:6443 which works in my case

```
k3d cluster create test --api-port 127.0.0.1:6443
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).